# Replicating header scroll effect from mobile app of facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So when you open the facebook app and scroll down the page the header slides off the top of the screen, then as soon as you scroll up the header slides down. The slide down can happen at any position in the document and always slides down immediately when you start scrolling up(so I'm not looking to have the header slide down once u scroll to the top of the document)

I kind of have it working, but if you scroll up and down over and over you will notice some of the header gets cut off, and the amount which gets cut off is completely random.

Here is the js and I have made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6kx2oL0/9/) of the problem

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var headerTop;
var headerTopMax;
var headerNewTop = 1;
var stMax;
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (st > lastScrollTop) {
        if (st > $(".header").height())
            headerTop = $(".header").height();
        else
            headerTop = st;

        //console.log("downscroll");

        $(".header").css("top", "-" + headerTop + "px");
        stMax = st;
        headerNewTop = 1;
        console.log("headerNewTop = " + headerNewTop);
    }
    else {
        headerTopMax = $(".header").height();

        if (headerNewTop > 0) {
            if (stMax % st != NaN) {
                headerNewTop = headerTopMax - ((stMax % st) + 1);
                $(".header").css("top", "-" + headerNewTop + "px");
            }

        }

        console.log("stMax % st = " + ((stMax % st) + 1));
        console.log("headerTop = " + headerTop);
        console.log("headerTopMax = " + headerTopMax);
        console.log("headerNewTop = " + headerNewTop);
        console.log("stMax = " + stMax);
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;

});
```

Can anyone help me figure t why it is doing this.
Cheers

Comment: I think it has something to do with scrolling and the amount of scroll that occurs with mouse wheel up and down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, seems there was a simpler way of doing this. Good ol CSS transition for the win ;)

HTML:

```
<body style="height: 1000px;">
<div class="header container-fluid scrollEffect" style="width: 100%; background: #ececec; text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;">
<img src="http://www.logopeople.com.au/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/free-australia-logo-design.jpg" width="150px" alt="" />
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.header.scrollEffect {
    transition: top linear 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: top linear 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: top linear 0.5s;
    -o-transition: top linear 0.5s;
}
```

JS:

```
var headerTop;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function (e) {
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (st > lastScrollTop) {
        if (st > $(".header").height())
            headerTop = $(".header").height();
        else
            headerTop = st;
        $(".header").css("top", "-" + headerTop + "px");
    }
    else {
        $(".header").css("top", "0px");
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;

});
```

Here is my updated [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6kx2oL0/12/) so you can see it in action :)